How to consider work function difference in gating?
For two metals forming a capacitance, we use $Q=CV$ to calculate the charge transfer between them, where $V$ is the voltage of the battery between them.
What I really feel confused about this simple model is, the battery voltage actually determines the Fermi energy difference between the two metals, but the electric potential difference between them is the difference of their "vacuum level", so it is the sum of Fermi energy difference and work function difference (work function is the difference of a metal's vacuum level and its Fermi surface, if we think the DOS at the metal's Fermi surface is infinitely large, then it does not depend on the density), and the charge transfer between them should be determined by the electric potential difference rather than Fermi level difference. So actually the charge transfer should be $Q=C \ (V+W_1/e-W_2/e)$, where $W_1$ and $W_2$ represent the work function of the two metals.
So, even if two metals are simply connected by a wire with no voltage applied, there will still be a charge transfer of $Q=C \ (W_1/e-W_2/e)$.
I have see in wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_function section: Measurement Kelvin probe method) that there's a "Kelvin probe method" which measures the work function difference between two materials based on the electric field between them, I think it shows that my understanding is correct.
However, I haven't seen any experiment considered this when calculating the charge gated into the sample, but there's no contradiction between the experiment result and the calculation of charge (For example, in a FQAHE experiment, the calculated filling factor correspond with the filling factor indicated by the quantized Hall resistance, however, in that experiment, work-function difference induced potential difference is of the same magnitude of the voltage they apply).
I find that it is admitted that for a junction between two different materials, there will be a charge transfer related to their work function difference, but I think for case where two metals are not in  directly contact but connected by a wire, there shall also be a charge transfer.
